# What does the notation $f[E]$ mean with $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $E \subseteq A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Context:

Show or disprove $f[\cap\chi]=\cap\{f[X]:X\in\chi\}$ for all $\chi\subseteq\mathcal{P}(A)$ with $\chi\neq\emptyset$

I don't know how to start because I don't know what the cornered brackets mean ín settheory.

Would be nice if somebody could give me a hint how to approach this excercise.

Comment: $f: A \rightarrow B$

Comment: Do you know what $\{f(a): a\in E\}$ is where $E$ is some subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is some real-valued function?

Comment: The set of all elements where the value remains in E

Comment: That's what $\{f(X): X\in\xi\}$ means.... I may have misunderstood your question now that I think about it. Is the confusion $f[X]$ as opposed to $f(X)$? The square bracket is just used to emphasize that $f[X]$ is a set instead of just a point.

Comment: No sorry I mean the set of all Pictures of Elements in E, I was a bit confused because you said that E is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and also that f is some real-valued function. In this case f: $\mathbb {R} \rightarrow \mathbb {R}$

Comment: $\{f(a): a\in E\}$ = $f(E)$?

Comment: yes, for that set equation.

Comment: $f(E) = f [E]$?

Comment: Let me just say that this is the first time I have seen that notation, and it is not standard. Standard is $Im_f(E)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f[A] = { f(x) : x in A }.
f[A] can also be written as f(A).
f[A] is the more precise notation.